# How to fix cors policy in java script it has been blocked by the api

Tags: ajax

I am creating login page using html and my api for login is REST API (django).
While running it is showing cors policy has been blocked. How to fix this error?
I have to change in some java script or in API.

```
 var username=document.getElementById('UserName').value;
                var password=document.getElementById('Password').value;

            var http = new XMLHttpRequest();
            var url = 'https://creativedsapi.kdns.in/hrapi/login';

            var params={

"username":username,
"password":password
};
                http.open('POST', url, true);

            //Send the proper header information along with the request
            http.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
            http.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
            http.onreadystatechange = function() {//Call a function when the state changes.
                if(http.readyState === 4 && http.status === 200) {
                alert(http.responseText);

                }
            }
            http.send(JSON.stringify(params));
```

Comment: Could you also include the error?

Comment: no while  i am communicating with the api it showing errot like this...'https://creativedsapi.kdns.in/hrapi/login' from origin 'http://localhost:8383' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

Comment: @NiyazMulla what is backend language you are using.

Comment: python(Django)..